# [ZXing]How to encode UPC_E and CODE_93 barcode?

Tags: android, zxing

I need to encode a number to barcode but there is no Code93Writer and 
UPCEWriter. How to encode these two barcode? or Zxing not support to encode these format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697001/android-zxing-get-barcode-image

Comment: You will have to write your own encoders if they do not exist